# Redirection to the web page not happening

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I have been trying to redirect the other web page from the home page in the node server.
Redirect is not happening to the link./idea.html where the relevant web page (HTML file)idea.html to be linked is also present.
can you guys help me whether there is any error in the code or any special function to be added

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<div>
<a href="https://www.sports_tournament/apple.com">apple</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

idea.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <title>thenewboston></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
<link rel="Registration" href="C:/Users/web/Mongodb/home.html" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It works when idea.html is the in same folder as that of index.html. There is no need for any function as such. You should put some content in idea.html to see if that works.

Comment: ...thanks for your reply.... Both the HTML files are in the same folder. Is there any other solution to solve the issue

Answer (score -1):

on same page why you have to redirect i think you have to use href="#" there

Comment: Question clearly states "I have been trying to redirect to other web page from the home page". There are also two HTML files so I'd guess that they are two separate pages.